# Trying to compare two columns that are numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to output the ones where the Units on Stock is less than the Units on Order. I'm trying to output the name, products on stock.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT ProductName, UnitsOnOrder, UnitsInStock 
FROM Product 
WHERE (SELECT UnitsInStock FROM Product) < (SELECT UnitsOnOrder);
```

Comment: That's not a valid SQL query. Suggest you find a tutorial on basic SQL formatting, like this on https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/where.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the attributes are in the Product table then I think this should work:

```
SELECT ProductName, UnitsInStock
FROM Product 
WHERE UnitsInStock < UnitsOnOrder
```

Comment: I actually kept it in at first, but then I reread the question: "I'm trying to output the name, products on stock"

Comment: Yeah, the words disagree with the sample query... anyway, this should work based on any reasonable interpretation of the question.